# PGP Encrypting a Zip File with Python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, encryption, zip, gnupg, pgp

I am regularly generating a zip of folders on a server and pushing these archives to a storage server.  To comply with data privacy regulations, we need to have these folder encrypted using a client's supplied public key.

I am using gnupg, and have imported the public key to the server.

```
stream = open('/home/user/myfile.zip','rb')
gpg.encrypt(stream,fingerprint,output='/home/user/myfile.zip.gpg')
```

However when using the private key to decrypt the file, the resulting zip file is a different size than the source zip, and is unreadable.  For example, the source zip file is 66KB, the decrypted file is 104KB.

I have had similar problems with other compressed test files: .jpg, .png, etc.

The only files I have successfully decrypted and opened are uncompressed text files - .txt and .css, so I know that the key pair is working.

When trying to open a decrypted zip file, the error I get is: "There was a problem reading the contents of "myfile.zip".  The archive file is incomplete".

EDIT: If I run the gpg command from Ubuntu it works correctly: gpg --homedir /home/user/.pgphome --output /home/user/myfile.zip.gpg --encrypt /home/user/myfile.zip, so this problem is isolated to Python.

Comment: If you try to encrypt/decrypt the same file from the shell (not from Python), do you have no problems?

Comment: you can't encrypted file ! allowed only bytes. Be carefull on opening style. if you think this not a good trick, [check this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/)

Comment: @boardrider If I run the command from Ubuntu it works correctly: gpg --homedir /home/user/.pgphome --output /home/user/myfile.zip.gpg --encrypt /home/user/myfile.zip

Comment: @dsgdfg, according to the gnupg documentation, data can either be a file or bytestream: encrypt(data, *recipients, **kwargs) Parameters: data (str) – The file or bytestream to encrypt.

Comment: This is not a real solution, but most probably will solve your problem -
import os
os.system("gpg --homedir /home/user/.pgphome --output /home/user/myfile.zip.gpg --encrypt /home/user/myfile.zip")

Comment: Thanks @TrigonaMinima. That's what I was fearing when boardrider's suggestion proved true.  If there's no native way to deal with it, I might use that method, but as you suggest, it's not the ideal solution :/  Cheers!

Comment: Which `gpg` module are you using?

Comment: gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16, and I've tried two versions of python-gnupg: the original, and a patched fork: https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg and pip install python-gnupg